# JavaScript para mostrar un div full pantalla

Tags: javascript

no se manipular el lenguaje de JavaScript por eso esta petición de ayuda. mi idea es hacer una cuenta regresiva y que cuando finalice el tiempo, me muestre un div full pantalla, el cual no me permita poder seguir utilizando las funciones de la pagina que es un repositorio de archivos.

el código que encontré es el siguiente, pero ni idea de como hacer para agregarle ese div.

```
<div class="countdown">
Limited Time Only!
<span id="clock"></span>
</div>
<script>
$('#clock').countdown('2023/09/15 20:58:56')
.on('update.countdown', function(event) {
var format = '%H:%M:%S';
if(event.offset.totalDays > 0) {
format = '%-d day%!d ' + format;
}
if(event.offset.weeks > 0) {
format = '%-w week%!w ' + format;
}
$(this).html(event.strftime(format));
})
.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
$(this).html('This offer has expired!')
.parent().addClass('disabled');
});
```

Muchas gracias por su atención

Comment: full pantalla no se puede, solo cuando sea con intervencion del usuario

Comment: Cuando dices `full pantalla` lo que uno entiende es que quieres hacer algo como cuando presionas `F11`, y según lo que veo no es lo que quieres (¿o si?), me parece que lo tu quieres es que ocupe todo el `viewport` (que es la sección "útil" del navegador). Investiga sobre las unidades `vh` y `vw` de css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba de la siguiente manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body style="position: relative;">
    <div class="countdown">
        Limited Time Only!
        <span id="clock"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="mostrar" hidden style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; position: absolute; z-index: 1000000001; background-color: red; top:0;">

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.2.0/jquery.countdown.min.js" integrity="sha512-lteuRD+aUENrZPTXWFRPTBcDDxIGWe5uu0apPEn+3ZKYDwDaEErIK9rvR0QzUGmUQ55KFE2RqGTVoZsKctGMVw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script>
        $('#clock').countdown('2023/09/18 18:34:25')
            .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
                var format = '%H:%M:%S';
                if (event.offset.totalDays > 0) {
                    format = '%-d day%!d ' + format;
                }
                if (event.offset.weeks > 0) {
                    format = '%-w week%!w ' + format;
                }
                $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
            })
            .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
                /*$(this).html('This offer has expired!')
                    .parent().addClass('disabled');*/
                $("#mostrar").removeAttr("hidden");
            });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

lo que hago aqui, es mostrar el div en posicion absoluta y sobre todos los demas elementos al momento de llegar el contador a 0